# My Android App bug on load ressource only in production

Tags: java, android, debugging, dynamic, production

I have a bug in my Android Java application only in production.

When I publish my application to my phone with Android Studio, all is working fine.

When I update this application by the Play Store on the same phone, I have this error:

```
Process: com.iddeos.planningbuilder, PID: 31989
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
```

Bug provides from this line, but I don't understand why

```
int iconRessource = getResources().getIdentifier("drawable/"+menu.getIcon(), "drawable", getPackageName());
Drawable image = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), iconRessource);
menuBottomConfig.add(android.view.Menu.NONE, menu.getId(), android.view.Menu.NONE, menu.getTitle()).setIcon(image);
```

Comment: what don't you use "menu.getIcon()" in this line directly?

menuBottomConfig.add(android.view.Menu.NONE, menu.getId(), android.view.Menu.NONE, menu.getTitle()).setIcon(menu.getIcon());

Just make sure getIcon() is not null.

Comment: I have try your solution and its the same issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have foud the solution.

Bugs not provide from ressource but by obfuscation mod.
Because GSON not working correctly in this mod.

A add proguard rules and its working now.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).